# Multilingual Taxonomy for a multisite Drupal installation

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, multilingual, taxonomy

I have a multisite Drupal installation. SO there are 17 sites pointing to the same code base with Domain Access as the key module. There are 17 sites and one of them happens to be a Spanish site. When the sites had been launched, there was a common taxonomy shared across all 17 sites which was in English (even on this Spanish site - btw the Spanish site has a base language as English).

Till now, all the content added to this site was in Spanish. However it had English Categories from the shared-common taxonomy. Now, it is required to convert this taxonomy to Spanish.

What is the best way to do it and have all existing content in this Spanish site posted under the common taxonomy to be migrated to Spanish taxonomy?

There is i18 module for multilingual site. and a multilingual taxonomy as well. However, it creates separate new entities. So it doesn't help. I need a Spanish translation for the taxonomy on this Spanish site.